# How can I return a number of likes in laravel withe ajax

Tags: php, laravel, social-media-like

here is my app.blade

```
$('.like').click(function(event) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
      url: "{{route('post.like','')}}/"+id,
    })
});
```

and here is my AdsController.php

```
public function likePost(Request $request){  
    $likePost=new Like;
    $likePost->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
    $likePost->ad_id= $request->id;
    $likePost->save();
}
```

when I click on like button the data insert in the likes table but I want to return the number of the likes in the view also

Comment: hi, did my answer below help solve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

In your `likePost` function, after you've saved the `Like` then do one of the following:

If you want to return the number of likes the user has:

```
$likes = Like::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->count();
```

If you want to return the number of likes the ad has:

```
$likes = Like::where('ad_id', $request->id)->count();
```

If you want to return the number of all likes:

```
$likes = Like::count();
```

Then, as it is an AJAX request, you will need to return a JSON response in your `likePost` function:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#json-responses

```
return response()->json([
    'likes' => $likes
]);
```

And in your JavaScript, pick up the response like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{route('post.like','')}}/"+id,
}).done(function(response) {
    var likes = response.likes; <-- num of likes
});
```

-- **edited** --

To show in the view, simply add a class or an id to the html element you want to display the number, for example:

`<div id="numberOfLikes"></div>`

You can then set it's inner html content using the response you got from AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{route('post.like','')}}/"+id,
}).done(function(response) {
    var likes = response.likes;
    $('#numberOfLikes').html(response.likes);
});
```

Comment: i try wihe that but it still insert in the base and dont return a number in the view

Comment: i have edited my answer to show you how to use the `response.likes` from the AJAX to show in your view